# Node JS function that takes an unsigned integer and returns wrong number of '1' bits

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

This Node JS function  takes input as  signed 2's complement and any particular reason why it returns wrong number of '1' bits
`Explanation: The input binary string 11111111111111111111111111111101 has a total of thirty one '1' bits.`

Here is function which should return the `output as 31` whereas it returns `1`

```
            var hammingWeight = function(n) {
                let count = 0;
                while (n !== 0) {
                  n = n & (n - 1);
                  count++;
                }
              
                return count;
              };

            console.log(hammingWeight(11111111111111111111111111111101))
```

Here is console output

```
            PS C:\VSB-PRO> node Fibo.js
            1
```

any reason what could have gone wrong in the javascript code,your help is highly appreciated

Regards,

Carolyn

Comment: Change to `0b11111111111111111111111111111101` and you will get 31.

Comment: Please don't use `var` any more.  Use `const` or `let`.

Comment: FYI, there are lots and lots of pitfalls trying to do binary bit manipulation operations in Javascript as it really just isn't built for that.

Comment: this ```0b11111111111111111111111111111101``` worked like a charm,what is the significance of adding ```0b``` as prefix?Thoughts?

Comment: You just have to specify you're declaring binary instead of decimal.  Just don't go over 31 bits long though as these values are still stored in a double internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `hammingWeight(101)`, you are not using the *binary string* 101<sub>2</sub> (4+1 = 5), but the decimal number 101<sub>10</sub> ([one hundred and one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/101_(number))). Try instead `hammingWeight(0b101)`.